# da error en un modelo inexistente

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

hice modificaciones en un modelo que estoy haciendo en odoo y lo cambie por completo pero a la hora de actualizar los cambios manda error en un modelo que elimine osea no existe y en la terminal manda error

Adjunto codigo python:

````
```class Bascula (models.Model):

_name=('mti_bascula')

vendor_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Provedor')
category_supplier_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner.category', string='Category Supplier', default=lambda self: self.env.ref('mti_assured.mti_assured_category_Carrier'))

vendor_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Provedor.')
category_supplier_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner.category', string='Category Supplier Mti', default=lambda self: self.env.ref('mti_assured.mti_assured_category_suppliers_mti') )

driver_sel = fields.Selection([('mti', 'Transporte MTI'),('ext', 'Transporte EXT.')], default='mti', required=True, string="Transporte")
driver_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Operador.')
driver_truck_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.fleet.operator', string='Operador')

number_plate = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.fleet', string='Placas Trac.')
num_plate_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='fleet.vehicle', string='Placas')

consignment_note = fields.Char(string='Carta Porte')

destiny = fields.Char(stirng='Destino')

VIA = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Aereo', 'Aereo'),
    ('Maritimo', 'Maritimo'),
    ('Terrestre', 'Terrestre'),

], string='Via')

partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Remitente')

consignee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Consignatario')
category_consignee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner.category', string='Category Consigne',default=lambda self: self.env.ref('mti_assured.mti_assured_category_consignee'))

receive = fields.Char(string='Recive')

seller_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee',string='Ejecutivo')

Commodity = fields.Char(string='Mercancia')

gross_weight = fields.Integer('Peso Bruto', digits='Product Price')```
````

este es el modelo en python al que le hice cambios y ahi mismo tenia el modelo detalle_bascula pero lo borre porque estaba mal la codificacion y de ahi es donde manda el error

Vista xml:

`````
```
  <odoo>

<record id="mti_bascula_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mti.bascula.form</field>
    <field name="model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <group col="2" string="Registro de Bascula">
                    <group string="Registro general">
                        <group>
                            <field name="driver_sel" widget="radio" />
                            <field name="vendor_id" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [category_supplier_id])]" attrs="{'invisible': [('driver_sel','!=','ext')]}" />
                            <field name="category_supplier_id" invisible='1' />
                            <field name="vendor_mti_id" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [category_supplier_mti_id])]" attrs="{'invisible': [('driver_sel','!=','mti')]}" />
                            <field name="category_supplier_mti_id" invisible='1' />
                            <field name="driver_mti_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('driver_sel','!=','mti')]}" />
                            <field name="driver_truck_id" domain="[('company_driver_id','=',vendor_id)]" attrs="{'invisible': [('driver_sel','!=','ext')]}" />
                            <field name="num_plate_mti_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('driver_sel','!=','mti')]}" />
                            <field name="number_plate" attrs="{'invisible': [('driver_sel','!=','ext')]}" />
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="consignee_id" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [category_consignee_id])]" options="{'no_quick_create':True, 'no_create_edit':True}" />
                            <field name="category_consignee_id" invisible='1' />
                            <field name="destiny"/>
                            <field name="VIA" required="1"/>
                            <field name="partner_id" />
                            <field name="consignee_id" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [category_consignee_id])]" options="{'no_quick_create':True, 'no_create_edit':True}" />
                            <field name="category_consignee_id" invisible='1' />
                            <field name="receive"/>
                            <field name="seller_id" />
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>


<record id="mti_bascula" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="res_model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>


<menuitem id="mti_menu_bascula" name="Bascula" parent="stock.menu_stock_root"  sequence="1"/>
<menuitem  action="mti_bascula" parent="mti_menu_bascula" id="bascula_menu" name="Bascula"   sequence="2"/>

        </odoo>````
`````

asi lo tengo plasmado en la vista pero no se bien donde sea el error que tendria que hacer para corregirlo

Comment: Probaste a eliminar los ficheros PYC que te genera la ejecución del código? en ocasiones tuve problemas similares y los solucionaba de esa forma

Comment: Hola. Devuelve el modulo original por lo menos el nombre _name y desinstalalo. O si lo puedes ver en las aplicaciones aun, pues solo desinstalalo.

Comment: @Legna listo funciono no se si me puedas ayudar con otra cosa que tengo que hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devuelve al modulo original por lo menos el nombre `_name` y desinstalalo. O si lo puedes ver en las aplicaciones aun, desinstalo.